# Display xvfb output in remote PC

Tags: ssh, x11, display, headless, xvfb

I have a Windows pc that I use to connect to my Ubuntu PC over ssh that I use as a server (18.04) that is connected only to the internet and power (No monitor). When I run `glxgears -info` I only get 8-10 fps while having a graphics card. When I run it as `xvfb-run glxgears -info` I get 2000~ fps (Which I assume because it uses my GPU to render). But I can't get `xvfb-run` to display in my Xming X server. Running `glxgears -info` displays in Xming but as I said, low performance, etc. How Can I make xvfb to display in Xming on my Windows machine? Or is there an easier/better way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run an Xserver to display remote Xclients (e.g. `glxgears`), you are stuck with the X display protocol which has poor performance, especially over slow links.

You get better performance with `Xvnc`, but it will normally use a virtual framebuffer and not benefit from the GPU on your Ubuntu machine. Enter `virtualgl`, this is what you need for your objective.
It is not trivial to set up, but there are good references out there, [this one](https://gist.github.com/cyberang3l/422a77a47bdc15a0824d5cca47e64ba2) specifically for Ubuntu.

HTH,

ppenguin

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and will let you know if it works

Comment: So, the cause of poor performance isn't becouse it uses onboard graphics, but x server?

Comment: @fedqx I'm no expert on Xvfb, but I think your issue between Xvfb and remote X is not 3D Acceleration related, but just 2D performance. You can improve that by just replacing X by Xvnc (use tightvnc encoding). If you **additionally** want your GPU to handle 3D acceleration (OpenGL), then you can get extra benefit from `virtualgl`

Comment: I followed the instructions, but somehow broke the system (PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorization protocol ) so I had to uninstall it. but thank you for helping.

Comment: and, my system is still broken...

Comment: I fixed it but, I dont think i am going to attempt that one more time. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: @fedqx: The PuTTY error is unrelated or due to wrong configuration. If you are using Xvnc, you should be using normal tunneling (e.g. `ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@remotehost` and connect your vnc client using `localhost:5901`), or if you're on a trusted LAN you could do without tunneling...